# Reading new line in C

Tags: c, file, input

So I'm currently trying to read a input file character by character and I'm trying to see when a new line occurs. I get all the characters fine, but instead of a '\n' for a new line I get 'á' or -97 if I cast it to an int. Here's my code and I'm using VS 2015.

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = open_input_file();
    if (fp != 0) {
        char ch = read_character(fp);
        int d = (int)ch;
        while (ch != EOF) {
            printf("%d\n", d);
            ch = read_character(fp);
            d = (int)ch;
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
char read_character(FILE *infile) {

    int c;
    c = getc(infile);

    return (char) c;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to ask? could you be more clear?

Comment: You keep casting to and from `int`. Just stick with `int`, as returned by `getc`, for the function type too..

Comment: Just think twice want it could mean that you need to use the casting hammer here: `return (char) c;`. A general rule of thumb in C: If you see yourself confronted with the need to cast your are either dump or smart. Normally you need to cast only under *very rare* circumstances.

Comment: `getc()` returns an `int` by intention. Just not ignore this.

Comment: 1) Insure `char read_character(FILE *infile)` is declared/defined before usage in `main()`.  2) Post content of the input file.  3) post output seen

Comment: this line: `while (ch != EOF) {` may or may not work, depending on if your C compiler implements a `signed char` or an `unsigned char` (due to sign extension if a signed char.)  Strongly suggest: 1) return an `int, from `read_character()` rather than a `char`.  Note: `EOF` is `-1` which is an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: the posted code: 1) is missing the `#include` statements.  Are we expected to guess what the OP actually included?  2) The prototype for `read_character()` is missing, so the compiler will ( depends somewhat on the version of the C standard used) assume all passed parameters and returned value are `int` where the function is called.

Comment: a `\n` is not a printable character.  Strongly suggest using `%x` to print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a newline with minor changes to your existing code:

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = open_input_file();
    if (fp != 0) {
        int ch = read_character(fp);//change to int return (getc() returns int)
        if(ch == '\n') //A simple comparison here will detect newline
        {
            printf("Found Newline: %d\n", ch);
        }
        ///int d = (int)ch;// not necessary with current changes
        while (ch != EOF) {
            //printf("%d\n", d);
            ch = read_character(fp);
            if(ch == '\n')//Note: ASCII for \n is value 10, or hex A
            {
                printf("Found newline: %d\n", ch);
            }

            //d = (int)ch;
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int read_character(FILE *infile) 
{  //changed prototype to return int

    int c;
    c = getc(infile);

    return c;//modified return value to int
}
```

Comment: With these changes there's no need for the `get_character` function in the first place, it's identical to `getc`.

Comment: This cast here `int d = (int)ch;` is useless.

Comment: @Barmer - true.  Not sure if more value to change here, or leave for OP to do.

Comment: @alk - agree'd, your are referring to the comment, right?  It is part of OPs original code.  I left in for contrast against changes.

Comment: I am referring to the code you show.

Comment: @alk - LOL, yes, I finally saw it, now commented.  Thanks.